# Struts 2 TextField Tag with an attribute and no value

Tags: struts2

I have a html tag in the following format:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter your username" required>
```

I am trying to convert it to be rendered by a struts tag (so that on validation error, the page reloads the value entered by the user):

```
<s:textfield name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter your username" required />
```

Unfortunately, struts throws the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(58,110) PWC6212: equal symbol expected
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:49)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:344)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:220)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:170)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1394)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1636)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:152)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:210)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:111)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:157)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:370)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:595)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:457)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:351)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
```

I'm guessing that Struts does not like the "required" not having a value. How can I edit my Struts tag to append the "required" text without a value? We have an existing javascript library which relies on the presence of "required" and not "required=""" or something else.

Comment: why don't you just use `input`

Answer (score 5):

**Here is an answer for anyone who finds this question and is running Struts 2.3.12 or higher - there appears to be very little documentation of this change on the web...**

Prior to version 2.3.12 struts2 had a required attribute which could be added to input fields. This attribute was purely to label the field as required and could be used to add required a required star/Asterisk (for example) next to the field through the use of .ftl files - it did not run any validation. It might have looked like this in your code:

```
<s:textfield key="name" type="text" required="true"/>
```

However after version 2.3.12 the required attribute was replaced with the requiredLabel attribute. It works in exactly the same way and might look like this:

```
<s:textfield key="name" type="text" requiredLabel="true"/>
```

This change is because of the introduction of the html5 required attribute. However note if you would like to use this in struts2 currently you cannot currently use it without providing a value (as the html5 specification says you can) - this seems to break struts. so for example this will not work:

```
<s:textfield key="name" type="text" required />
```

You will instead need to write:

```
<s:textfield key="name" type="text" required="required" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the "required" attribute fully:

```
<s:textfield ... required="required" />
```

This is how JSP/XHTML works, AFAIK.

I can't imagine the JS library would care if there was a value or not.

Comment: Every bit of documentation i have seen states that this attribute should be set to required="true"

Comment: @Suipaste Perhaps you missed the HTML spec - http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute - which states "If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace." And "**Note:** The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes."

Comment: Just done some extensive googling and found the reason behind this. Prior to struts2 2.3.12 the required attribute took in required="true" as the attribute. However after this version the required attribute for struts2 was changed to requiredLabel to differentiation between the html5 required attribute. My comment was specifically with reguards to struts2 but as it turns out was out of date.

Source - https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=967

Comment: @Suipaste Oh, that; gotcha.