# How to make a file upload in a form required in Struts 2

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2

I have a JSP which is a form, it is just a file upload and a submit button.

In the action class' validate method, I check to see if the File object is null.

The conditional statement evaluates to true, but the field error does not get displayed, instead the program runs into a NullPointerException later on. Which is what I was trying to mitigate with the validation.

I have also tried catching the exception in a try catch, but this just kicks the can further down the road and the exception is thrown for the validate method.

**Struts.xml**

```
            <!-- Displays a form for adding items -->
        <action name="addItemsForm">
            <result name="success">addItems.jsp</result>
        </action>


        <!-- Adds a TSV of items to the DB -->
        <action name="addItems" class="AddItems">
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">getItems</result>
            <result name="input">addItems.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

**JSP:**

```
<s:form theme="simple" namespace="/my/space" action="addItems" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="divTable">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divParameterEntry">
                TSV File:
            </div>
            <div class="divParameterEntry">
                <s:file accept=".tsv" name="items"/>
            </div>
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <s:submit value="submit" name="submit" cssStyle="width: 80px; height:30px;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</s:form>

<br/>

<s:if test="hasFieldErrors()">
    <span style="color:red;">
    <s:fielderror />
    </span>
</s:if>
```

**Action Class' Validate Method:**

```
private File items;

public void validate() {
    if (items == null)
        addFieldError("items", "Please upload a file before submitting");

    path = items.getAbsolutePath(); // The NullPointerException stems from here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was actually a very simple solution to this problem that I simply wasn't aware of, but just stumbled across while working on something else.

I was able to make the upload mandatory by adding required to the struts file tag in the JSP as follows:

```
<s:file accept=".tsv" name="items" required="required"/>
```

This prevents a user from submitting the form without a file uploaded and requires no javascript, ajax, etc...

To understand why it is set to 'required' instead of true, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32245226/5696071)